# How can I stop text-shadow being applied to text-decoration?

Tags: html, css

In CSS is it possible to stop `text-shadow` being applied to a `text-decoration`?

I have a menu system which needs a text shadow on the first letter of a word, (as the client has requested a lighter (*white*) background). On mouse hover over the link; the `text-decoration` is employed, which works fine but now that there is a `text-shadow` element, this also applies to the `text-decoration`.

Is there a way of working around this so the text-shadow only applies to the text iself and not superfluous decorations?

## Code:

```css
nav > a {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    background:url('/images/menu-log60.png') no-repeat left;
    padding:22px 0 22px 25px;
    padding:calc(30px - 0.5em) 0 calc(30px - 0.5em) 25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
}
nav a > strong {
    color: #ffe100;
}
nav #orderingSubMenu a >strong {
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #721006, -1px 0 0 #721006,  0 1px 0 #721006, 0 -1px 0 #721006;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span id="orderingSubMenu">
      <a href="/#"><strong>P</strong>rices - Loose</a>
      <a href="/#"><strong>P</strong>rices - Bags</a>
      <a href="/#"><strong>A</strong>ccount Details</a>
      <a href="/#"><strong>L</strong>og Out</a>
  </span>
</nav>
```

```
/*** Current work around ***/
nav #orderingSubMenu a:hover > strong,
nav #orderingSubMenu a:focus > strong {
     text-shadow: none;
 }
```

I have found no method to do this and suspect it can't be done, due to `text-` CSS rulesapplying equally to all `text-` parts (such as `-decoration`, etc.).

## Current Setup:

[image]

## Current Problem on mouse hover:

[image]

## Current workaround Soluton:

[image]

## Ideal Solution:

[image]

Any ideas how I can achieve this ideal solution?

## Update 1: Why I can't use `Border-bottom`

After good ideas from **CBroe** [and **Michael_B**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45962142/3536236) re adding `border-bottom` I did explore this option but found that the nature of the CSS setup of the menu (*not* all displayed above for this MCVE) meant that even turning the various padding values into margin values meant that either there was a border under the whitespace or that the text position in the layout changed.

I suppose I could rewrite the whole structure of the menu system CSS but that's an excessive time spent (*more excessive than this question? Who knows, but time spent on this question + time spent recoding the CSS....*) so I don't want to do that unless no other options are present.

## Update 2: Why I can't use `span`s

<strike>As [suggested by **myf**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961944/css-stop-text-shadow-being-applied-to-text-decoration/45962142?noredirect=1#comment78883249_45962142) to use `spans` to encase the shadow; this doesn't work as the `text-shadow`applies to all child elements, so I'd have to have the text shadow set on the *parent* of the anchor element but only applying to the first letter of the anchor text, which actually leads me to an idea....</strike>

I misunderstood **Myf**'s workaround. Using his answer solved my issue.

## Update 3: Unable to break the anchor element into parts:

I have tried to split the anchor element into parts; so that for the main element the text-decoration applies except for `:first-letter` it would not apply;

```
nav #orderingSubMenu a:first-letter:hover, nav #orderingSubMenu a:first-letter:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #721006;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

But this does not work; I can't "break" anchors into constituant parts. I could create multiple anchors (one for first letter and one for the rest of the link, but then this will appear inconsistent when hovering, maybe some Javascript can make both separate anchors act as if they're unified....

Comment: Use a border-bottom instead of text-decoration? (If that seems to sit “too low”, play with the line-height as well.)

Comment: @CBroe what a nice idea. I hadn't even registered that..... doh... I will experiment....

Comment: `border-bottom` would definitely help you.

Comment: Yep. And instead of `strong` you can use `:first-letter`. :)

Comment: or something like `background-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, transparent 2px, red 0, red 3px, transparent 0)` -- you can adjust position of the line without altering `line-height`

Comment: The CSS for this site is a little old, @Huelfe yes `:first-letter` is a good idea. (More work. lol.) . CBroe, the `border-bottom` is also problematic as the "indent" of the menu items uses padding and the border would not sit just under the text; but I'm playing with the options here.....

Comment: A major cheat for this problem would be adding a ::before pseudo element that would block the text-shadow of the first letter. Could that work for you?

Comment: @joshuamiller can you explain that further? Sounds like the first letter would then not have a shadow at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra bordered inline wrapper around text:

```css
nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
}
nav span {
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
nav a strong {
    color: #ffe100;
}
nav #orderingSubMenu a strong {
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #721006, -1px 0 0 #721006,  0 1px 0 #721006, 0 -1px 0 #721006;
}
nav a:hover span, nav a:focus span {
 border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span id="orderingSubMenu">
      <a href="/#"><span><strong>P</strong>rices - Loose</span></a>
      <a href="/#"><span><strong>P</strong>rices - Bags</span></a>
      <a href="/#"><span><strong>A</strong>ccount Details</span></a>
      <a href="/#"><span><strong>L</strong>og Out</span></a>
  </span>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `text-decoration`, consider using `border-bottom`.

```css
nav > a {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    background:url('/images/menu-log60.png') no-repeat left;
    padding:22px 0 22px 25px;
    padding:calc(30px - 0.5em) 0 calc(30px - 0.5em) 25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; /* prevents box shifting on hover
                                             (by factoring in the border width) */
}
nav a > strong {
    color: #ffe100;
}
nav #orderingSubMenu a >strong {
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #721006, -1px 0 0 #721006,  0 1px 0 #721006, 0 -1px 0 #721006;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
    /* text-decoration:underline; */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <span id="orderingSubMenu">
        <a href="/#"><strong>P</strong>rices - Loose</a>
        <a href="/#"><strong>P</strong>rices - Bags</a>
        <a href="/#"><strong>A</strong>ccount Details</a>
        <a href="/#"><strong>L</strong>og Out</a>
    </span>
</nav>
```

Comment: I read your question, then turned to another screen to test my solution. Didn't see the comments that came in the meanwhile. Credit to @Cbroe for posting this answer first.

Comment: It's always quicker to post a comment than to posted a fixed code answer.... but credits go to the answer not the comment! `:-D`

Comment: unfortunately `border-bottom` doesn't fit with other aspects of the menu systems layout CSS. Even converting `padding`s to `margin`s, is there an alternative solution?

Comment: can you add extra `<span></span>` around text content in the link?

Comment: @myf I tried with span but the `text-shadow` applies to all child elements

Comment: In fact I meant to abandon the `text-decoration`, like others suggested, and use border or background-image instead. The only problem without extra inline wrapper would be the block-level nature of the menu links…

Comment: …causing visually overlapping underline. That cold be solved with aforementioned extra inline element to apply the decoration to (see example in my answer). It is basically @Michael_B approach but without that `block` to `inline-block` on `:hover` swapping, which is barely usable in production.

Comment: @myf, yours is a clean and elegant solution. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, this is a big cheat but seems to work reasonably well.

```css
nav > a {
        display: block;
        vertical-align: top !important;
        background:url('/images/menu-log60.png') no-repeat left;
        padding:22px 0 22px 25px;
        padding:calc(30px - 0.5em) 0 calc(30px - 0.5em) 25px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    nav a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #000;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a > strong {
        color: #ffe100;
    }
    nav #orderingSubMenu a >strong {
        text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #721006, -1px 0 0 #721006,  0 1px 0 #721006, 0 -1px 0 #721006;
    }
    
    nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    nav a:hover::before, nav a:focus::before {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 1px;
        min-width: 11px;
        min-height: 1px;
        background: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    nav a:hover::after, nav a:focus::after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 3px;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 11px;
        min-height: 1px;
        background: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
      <span id="orderingSubMenu">
          <a href="/#"><strong>P</strong>rices - Loose</a>
          <a href="/#"><strong>P</strong>rices - Bags</a>
          <a href="/#"><strong>A</strong>ccount Details</a>
          <a href="/#"><strong>L</strong>og Out</a>
      </span>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I'm cautious with using absolute `px` offsets and dimensions, but otherwise this looks really interesting. I've just finished setting up myf's solution and that works well, but this is probably a handy reserve `:)`

Comment: You can always try using % offsets or some other unit. Either way, myf's solution is better so go with that. I posted this when you wrote you thought his implementation doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea

1. stop applying 'text-decoration:underline' to strong elm
2. append sufficient space as placeholder in anchor elm, such that spaces will be underline
3. pull strong elm(no underline) to the left so that it visually sits on top of the placeholder(underlined)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/zw1v291b/)

For point 1, I force strong elm to have its own stacking context.

```
strong { display:inline-block; opacity:1 }
```

For point 2, since strong elm contains one character only, the placeholder should be as wide as this character. However, there does not exist a character fitting 2/3em wide, so I chose two (1/3em space character)s as placeholder

```
a:before { content:'\002004\002004' }
```

For point 3, I use negative `text-indent`, the value is -2/3em roughly.

```
strong { text-indent:-0.667em }
```